# Setting a lower limit on calculation time

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation

Sometimes it can come in handy to set a lower limit for a calculation. Consider for example an animation that is generated by some infinite loop, which would run way too fast to display properly for the user. For this reason, I need a function of the type "pause at least". It would be like a little brother of [`TimeConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TimeConstrained.html).

*I threw together the following small code which seems to do the trick, but I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient or elegant solution for this?*

Here's my version if you're interested, it's pretty straightforward:

```
pauseAtLeast[calculation_, pause_] :=
    Block[{start, result},
        start = AbsoluteTime[];
        result = calculation;
        If[AbsoluteTime[] < start + pause,
            Pause[start + pause - AbsoluteTime[]]
        ];
        result
    ]
SetAttributes[pauseAtLeast, HoldFirst];
```

Usage:

```
(* Pauses 2 seconds *)
AbsoluteTiming@pauseAtLeast[Pause[2], 1]
(* Pauses 1 second *)
AbsoluteTiming@pauseAtLeast[Pause[.5], 1]
```

Comment: David, I notice that you have Accepted answers to nearly all of your questions, but not this one.  An oversight, or was it never answered to your satisfaction?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The answers provided don't really add anything to my naive implementation. When I asked this, I wondered whether maybe there's a built-in function to handle this (plus all possible special cases I could think of).

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

A similar but slightly shorter solution...

```
SetAttributes[pauseAtLeast2, HoldFirst]; 

pauseAtLeast2[calculation_, pause_] := 
   With[{res = AbsoluteTiming[calculation]},
        If[res[[1]] < pause, 
               Pause[pause - res[[1]]]
        ]; 

        res[[2]]
   ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as Andy but in terse style:

```
SetAttributes[holdFor, HoldFirst];

holdFor[op_, hold_] :=
  (Pause[# UnitStep@#] &[hold - #]; #2) & @@ AbsoluteTiming @ op
```