# Time delayed evaluation of a function

Tags: evaluation, scheduling

I'd like to write a function that delays the evaluation of a function (say) $5$ seconds after I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. Is this possible?

Comment: The tag is wrong. I'd like to use the tag `clock` but it is new, and I'm not allowed to create new tags.

Comment: Related: [(473)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/473), [(1565)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1565)

Answer (score 6):

Use the Pause function:

```
SetAttributes[delayedFunction, {HoldFirst}];
delayedFunction[function_] := (Pause[5]; function);
```

Comment: More useful if defined as `delayedFunction[function_, dt_] := (Pause[dt]; function)`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use the built in function, *RunScheduledTask*

```
Dynamic[z]
RunScheduledTask[z = 7, {5}]
```